# Like with substring

Tags: c#, sql-server

What I'm trying to do in the below code is to let users add '%' first if they want to search for cat starts with a char.

```
if (textBox1.text.StartsWith("%"))
{
    sql = "Select cat from items where cat like '%" +textBox1.text.Substring(1)+"'";
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(dataReader.GetString(0));
    }
    dataReader.Close();
    command.Dispose();
```

But nothing is shown in the list box.

Comment: Please be aware of [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) (a.k.a. [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

Comment: _cat starts with a char_ means `%` at the end

Comment: % is like a wildcard, if you want "starts with" then it should be at the end of your like clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get any results if you take the generated sql and run it directly towards the database?

If you want to search for items starting with a specific char the syntax is `like 'x%'` if `x` is your character. You currently have the percentage sign and the characters switched and are asking the database for all cats **ending** with your specified character. To search for cats starting with a specific character you want:

```
sql = "Select cat from items where cat like '" +textBox1.text.Substring(1)+"%'";
```

Comment: the issue with sql injection is still left